# to solve error TypeError: setFormValues is not a function REACT NEXT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a main component with rendering components of form depends on steps.
Code is written with React and Next.js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

```
import FormCard from "./formCard";

import {PersonalInfo} from "./forms/PersonalInfo";
import {Address} from './forms/Address'

export function Home(){
  const [formStep, setFormStep] = useState(0);

  const nextFormStep = () => setFormStep((currentStep) => currentStep + 1);

  const prevFormStep = () => setFormStep((currentStep) => currentStep - 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormCard currentStep={formStep} prevFormStep={prevFormStep}>
        {formStep >= 0 && (
          <PersonalInfo formStep={formStep} nextFormStep={nextFormStep} />
        )}
        {formStep >= 1 && (
          <Address formStep={formStep} nextFormStep={nextFormStep} />
        )}
        {formStep >= 2 && (
         <PersonalInfo formStep={formStep} nextFormStep={nextFormStep} />
        )} 
      </FormCard>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component PersonalInfo

```
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup"
import * as Yup from "yup"
import { PersonalFormContainer } from '../styled'
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useFormData } from '@/context/useForms'



export function PersonalInfo({ formStep, nextFormStep }) {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
    last_name: Yup.string().required("Last name is required"),
    email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email("Email is invalid"),
    phone: Yup.string().required("Phone is required"),
  });

  const formOptions = { resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema) };
  // get functions to build form with useForm() hook
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm(formOptions);
  const { errors } = formState

  const { setFormValues } = {} ?? useFormData();
  function onSubmit(data) {
   

    setFormValues(data);
    nextFormStep();
  }
  return (
    <PersonalFormContainer className="container">
      <h2 className="container__title">Complete Your Reservation</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="reset" className="form">
        <div className="py-1">
          <label className="form__title" htmlFor="first_name">FIRST NAME *</label>
          <div className="form__field">
            <input
              {...register("first_name")}
              name="first_name"
              type="text"
              className="form__input"
              id="first_name"
            />
            <div className={errors.first_name ? 'form__error' : ''}>{errors.first_name?.message}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="py-1">
          <label htmlFor="last_name">
            LAST NAME *
          </label>
          <div className="form__field">
            <input
              {...register("last_name")}
              name="last_name"
              type="text"
              id="last_name"
              className="form__input"
            />
            <div className={errors.last_name ? 'form__error' : ''}>
              {errors.last_name?.message}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="py-1">
          <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium" htmlFor="email">
            Email *
          </label>
          <div className="form__field">
            <input
              {...register("email")}
              name="email"
              type="text"
              id="email"
              className="form__input"
            />
            <div className={errors.email ? 'form__error' : ''}>
              {errors.email?.message}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="py-1">
          <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium" htmlFor="phone">
            PHONE *
          </label>
          <div className="form__field">
            <input
              {...register("phone")}
              name="phone"
              type="number"
              id="phone"
              className="form__input"
            />
            <div className={errors.phone ? 'form__error' : ''}>
              {errors.phone?.message}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="py-1">
          <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium" htmlFor="phone">
            COMMENTS
          </label>
          <div className="form__field">
            <textarea
              {...register("comments")}
              name="comments"
              type="text"
              id="comments"
              className="form__input"
              placeholder="Comments"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form__btn"
          $display="flex"
          $justifyContent="flex-end">
          <button
            type="submit"
          >
            Continue
          </button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </PersonalFormContainer>
  )
}
```

And saving context logics

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const FormContext = createContext();

export default function FormProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const setFormValues = (values) => {
    setData((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      ...values,
    }));
  };


  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ data, setFormValues }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useFormData = () => useContext(FormContext);
```

When I call setFormValues(data) from child component I'm getting error

TypeError: setFormValues is not a function
Why and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to wrap your child components with `FormProvider`?

Comment: @IgorDanchenko what do you mean? and why?

Comment: You are trying to use the `useFormData` hook, but you are not rendering `FormProvider ` anywhere in your code.